# In documentation, why is BluetoothServerSocket.accept() called in a while loop if it blocks the thread anyway?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

In the android documentation, the following code occurs in the run() segment of a thread:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                mmServerSocket.close();
                break;
            }
        }
```

However, the accept() method blocks the thread. I therefore do not understand why a while() loop is needed, especially since in all possible situations the while loop is broken in its first run.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wish I could accept this as an answer, thanks

Comment: Well now you can :-|

Comment: Already have, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally there wouldn't be a break after accepting and processing one socket: you would loop accepting sockets indefinitely.

It's a stupid example.

Comment: @gedo I have no idea why Android would post such a stupid example, and neither do you, and SO is not the place for guesswork of this nature. I consider it far more likely that it was simply cut down from another example of something else and then the missing `break` added to make it work, but all this guesswork is completely off-topic.